# why does mediainfo not give metadata of an image like exiftool does?

Tags: debian, images, exif

I have been scratching my head on this for quite some time now. Let's see what mediainfo says on an image -

```
$ mediainfo ZQs3vcsHiGY.jpg
General
Complete name                            : ZQs3vcsHiGY.jpg
Format                                   : JPEG
File size                                : 895 KiB

Image
Format                                   : JPEG
Width                                    : 2 500 pixels
Height                                   : 1 576 pixels
Color space                              : YUV
Chroma subsampling                       : 4:2:0
Bit depth                                : 8 bits
Compression mode                         : Lossy
Stream size                              : 895 KiB (100%)
ColorSpace_ICC                           : RGB
```

Now let's see the same image in exiftool -

```
$ exiftool ZQs3vcsHiGY.jpg
ExifTool Version Number         : 10.80
File Name                       : ZQs3vcsHiGY.jpg
Directory                       : .
File Size                       : 895 kB
File Modification Date/Time     : 2018:04:12 10:40:35+05:30
File Access Date/Time           : 2018:04:15 12:43:28+05:30
File Inode Change Date/Time     : 2018:04:12 10:40:35+05:30
File Permissions                : rw-r--r--
File Type                       : JPEG
File Type Extension             : jpg
MIME Type                       : image/jpeg
JFIF Version                    : 1.01
Resolution Unit                 : inches
X Resolution                    : 72
Y Resolution                    : 72
XMP Toolkit                     : XMP Core 4.4.0-Exiv2
Source URL                      : https://unsplash.com/photos/ZQs3vcsHiGY
Source Type                     : unsplash
Author                          : rawpixel.com
Source Name                     : Unsplash.com
Sfw Rating                      : 100
Image URL                       : https://unsplash.com/photos/ZQs3vcsHiGY/download
Author URL                      : https://unsplash.com/@rawpixel
Source Location                 : https://unsplash.com
Creator                         : rawpixel.com
Profile CMM Type                : Linotronic
Profile Version                 : 2.1.0
Profile Class                   : Display Device Profile
Color Space Data                : RGB
Profile Connection Space        : XYZ
Profile Date Time               : 1998:02:09 06:49:00
Profile File Signature          : acsp
Primary Platform                : Microsoft Corporation
CMM Flags                       : Not Embedded, Independent
Device Manufacturer             : Hewlett-Packard
Device Model                    : sRGB
Device Attributes               : Reflective, Glossy, Positive, Color
Rendering Intent                : Perceptual
Connection Space Illuminant     : 0.9642 1 0.82491
Profile Creator                 : Hewlett-Packard
Profile ID                      : 0
Profile Copyright               : Copyright (c) 1998 Hewlett-Packard Company
Profile Description             : sRGB IEC61966-2.1
Media White Point               : 0.95045 1 1.08905
Media Black Point               : 0 0 0
Red Matrix Column               : 0.43607 0.22249 0.01392
Green Matrix Column             : 0.38515 0.71687 0.09708
Blue Matrix Column              : 0.14307 0.06061 0.7141
Device Mfg Desc                 : IEC http://www.iec.ch
Device Model Desc               : IEC 61966-2.1 Default RGB colour space - sRGB
Viewing Cond Desc               : Reference Viewing Condition in IEC61966-2.1
Viewing Cond Illuminant         : 19.6445 20.3718 16.8089
Viewing Cond Surround           : 3.92889 4.07439 3.36179
Viewing Cond Illuminant Type    : D50
Luminance                       : 76.03647 80 87.12462
Measurement Observer            : CIE 1931
Measurement Backing             : 0 0 0
Measurement Geometry            : Unknown
Measurement Flare               : 0.999%
Measurement Illuminant          : D65
Technology                      : Cathode Ray Tube Display
Red Tone Reproduction Curve     : (Binary data 2060 bytes, use -b option to extract)
Green Tone Reproduction Curve   : (Binary data 2060 bytes, use -b option to extract)
Blue Tone Reproduction Curve    : (Binary data 2060 bytes, use -b option to extract)
Image Width                     : 2500
Image Height                    : 1576
Encoding Process                : Baseline DCT, Huffman coding
Bits Per Sample                 : 8
Color Components                : 3
Y Cb Cr Sub Sampling            : YCbCr4:2:0 (2 2)
Image Size                      : 2500x1576
Megapixels                      : 3.9
```

I went to mediainfo upstream and saw this [page](https://mediaarea.net/Vote) but was unable to comprehend which feature to vote for so it will give more metadata info. for images.

I did also scour the local manpage as well as --help but was not able to get far. I do know that mediainfo is suited more for video and audio files rather than images but would be nice if one tool could do it all.

I am running exiftool 10.80-1 and

```
$ mediainfo --version
MediaInfo Command line, 
MediaInfoLib - v18.03
```

on Debian testing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is for `mediainfo` to support EXIF metadata (which is not one of the listed proposals on that page as far as I can tell). You should suggest it to them if you want the feature.